# Create AWS container without programatic access

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I need to create a AWS container with ECS. However, I don't have programatic access for push the image in the ECR repository and I don't found other way to create a container.

My question is: Is there another way to create a container without programatic access?

I found a way to upload the image in Amazon S3 (compress the image into a .zip), but I don't know how to use the image after the upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found a way to upload the image in Amazon S3 (compress the image into a .zip)

That isn't going to work. You need to upload the image to ECR, not S3. ECS does not support loading images from S3.

> Is there another way to create a container without programatic access?

You can't upload images to ECR without programmatic access. It isn't possible to upload images to ECR with only username/password access.

Answer (score 0):

Formal (Correct) way:
Probably a CodeBuild job that builds the image and pushes it, possibly wrapped up with CodePipeline

Hacky way:
Maybe a lambda that pulls the zip, unpacks the image and pushes to ecr? Would definitely not be a pattern you want to house long term but might get the job done?